# Question on improved SSME thrust chamber construction

Tags: rockets, propulsion, engine-design

How do you get the closed out copper liner of the thrust chamber, which is hour glass shaped, into a jacket that is also the exact same shape like shown? I'm gonna guess it was done by diffusion bonding of two halves?

[image: New Thrust Chamber]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right on the two halves, but they were welded together.

> The chamber jacket provides the structural strength for the MCC. The
> jacket is approximately 20 inches long and is formed and machined in
> two matched halves. The halves are placed around the liner and welded
> to each other and to inlet and outlet coolant manifolds, which in turn
> are welded to the liner. A throat band, which provides additional
> structural strength, and two thrust vector control actuator strut
> assemblies are also welded to the jacket.

This is quoted from the old (pre-flight) Rockwell document [*Space Shuttle Main Engine Design Features* (BC73-110)](https://archive.org/download/ssme-design-features-1973_202401/SSME_Design_Features_1973.pdf) page 304-115T.

The 1998 [Space Shuttle Main Engine Orientation](http://large.stanford.edu/courses/2011/ph240/nguyen1/docs/SSME_PRESENTATION.pdf) presentation (which references the Large Throat MCC, although I am not sure the text was 100% updated to reflect that) also states

> The jacket halves are placed around the liner and welded.

[image]

Comment: this one seems to be referring to the original straight walled jacket

Comment: @MeatballPrincess good point, it is an old document. But the only one I have that talks construction details. And welcome back, have not seen your memorable user name in a while.

Comment: @MeatballPrincess I found a newer reference. Still welded.